# How to get specific value in web request response

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am making a web request in powershell using `$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $RequestUrl -Method $apiMethod -Body $token -ErrorAction:Stop -UseBasicParsing`.
It returns a response that looks like:

```
{
  "data" : [ {
    "deviceUid" : "02177890UHASBTE",
    "esn" : "075923846YR",
    "deviceName" : "HGY711018"
  } ],
  "metadata" : { }
}
```

I need to be able to access the value of the deviceName key, but I can't seem to find how to get it from the request object. I have tried $Result['data'][0]['deviceName'] but it does not work it just gives me nothing.

Comment: `($Result |ConvertFrom-Json).data[0].deviceName` should do the trick. You can also use `Invoke-RestMethod` in place of `Invoke-WebRequest`, it'll automatically attempt the conversion from JSON for you

Comment: Thanks that solved it. I don't work in powershell much so I don't really keep in memory how to do these things.